# Emberjs access a nested property

Tags: ember.js

This question is the following of this one [emberjs display an object return from an ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859880/emberjs-display-an-object-return-from-an-ajax-call)

To resume a bit, I have a dynamic list generated with some button for each item of that list. I catch the event of any button with this class :

```
App.EnquiriesView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var that = this;

        this.$().on('click', '.view-btn', function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('data-value');
            that.get('controller').send('clickBtn', id);
        });
    }
});
```

And it goes to my controller here :

```
App.EnquiriesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        clickBtn: function( id ) {
            console.log('DEBUG: ClickBtn OK id = ' + id);
            //console.log(App.Enquiries.findOne(id));

            this.transitionToRoute('enquiry', /*App.Enquiries.findOne(id)*/id);
        }
    }
});
```

The router related :

```
App.EnquiryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function( param ) {
        console.log('Enquiry id = ' + param.enquiry_id);
        return App.Enquiries.findOne(param.enquiry_id);
    }
});
```

and my map :

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('login', { path: '/' });
    this.resource('home');
    this.resource('enquiries', function (){
        this.route('create');
    });
    this.resource('enquiry', { path: 'enquiry/:enquiry_id' }, function(){
            this.route('update');
        });
});
```

So far for now when the user click on the button its redirect correctly to the enquiry with the good URL (e.g : /#/enquiry/1)

But the problem is coming from my update class now. I've just create a button with the action helper to display the update form :

```
App.EnquiryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        update: function() {
            console.log('DEBUG: in EnquiryController update');
            console.log(this.get('model'));
            this.transitionToRoute('enquiry.update');
        }
    }
});
```

So when you click on the update button you are redirected to this kind of URL : /#/enquiry/undefined/update instead of /#/enquiry/1/update ...

I don't know how this can happen and how I can loose my id during the process...

Thanks for your help.

[edit] If you need to know what is my findOne function :

```
findOne: function(id) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: host + 'mdf/enquiry/' + id,
        type: 'GET',
        accepts: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('DEBUG: GET Enquiry ' + id + ' OK');
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('DEBUG: GET Enquiry ' + id + ' Failed');
        }
    });
}
```

Its fetching the data from the server for every item after you've click on the related button in the list.

Here is the object I've got back :

```
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
responseJSON: Object
responseText: "{"ok":true,"enquiry":{"id":1,"domainid":"domain","userid":"userid","status":null,"type":"new","customerName":"Marco","customerEmail":"Marco@email.com",...}"
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "OK"
success: function () {
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: The issue is that your model is not matching any property to `enquiry_id`.  What does `App.Enquiries.findOne(param.enquiry_id)` return?

Comment: Its returning the enquiry with the id related. if you click on the first item with the id=1 the url would be /#/enquiry/1 and them the findOne will fetch the data on my server.

Comment: Yes... but what data is that?  The entire issue you're facing revolves around the fact that your model data is formatted differently than your map expects to receive it.  Provide the object that is returned as your model.

Comment: Its an object in which I have a field called : responseText: "{"ok":true,"enquiry":{"id":1,"domainid":"motorpark","userid":"motorpark/mpuser","status":null,"type":"new","customerName":"Marco","customerEmail":"Marco@email.com","customerPhone":"0123456789",...}}"

Comment: Please add that to the post, not as a comment.  It's really not readable without formatting.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of issues going on here.  A couple of things you're doing are very "non-ember" idiomatic, and I wouldn't be surprised if further issues pop up as a result.  But I'll focus on the question asked, and if you want more advice on adjusting further segments I'm happy to provide it.

In short, you have the following code:

```
this.resource('enquiry', { path: 'enquiry/:enquiry_id' });
```

in your map, but an enquiry object that looks *something* like:

```
{"ok":true,
"enquiry":{
    "id":1,
    "domainid":"motorpark",
    "userid":"motorpark/mpuser"‌​
    ...
    }   
}
```

And these don't match.  Your map defines that it is serialized by a field `enquiry_id` *which does not exist on your model.  To fix this you can do one of these solutions:

### Solution 1: Adjust your model

If you want to keep your map as is, you'll need to adjust your model to have an `enquiry_id` field, such as:

```
{"ok":true,
"enquiry_id":1,
"enquiry":{
    "id":1,
    "domainid":"motorpark",
    "userid":"motorpark/mpuser"‌​
    ...
    }   
}
```

### Solution 2:  Adjust your Map (recommended)

It's easier to just change your map though.  To do this, replace your enquiry resource on the map with:

```
this.resource('enquiry', {path: 'enquiry/:enquiry.id'});
```

The `.` tells ember that the desired element is the `id` field within the `enquiry` object.

You'll also need to modify how you access the param value.  Because you're naming an element of the param as `enquiry.id` you need to specify this as a variable name and not a path when retrieving the value.  On your route, change all instances of:

```
param.enquiry_id
```

To:

```
param['enquiry.id']
```

Comment: I know that there is a lot of non-ember doing in my project, but its because I'm using YUI in parallel and this is making ember a little bit more complicated.. Otherwise I would just use a {{#link-to}} to access to my enquiry with ember-data as well... And I've try your second solution but its not working, its seems that the model can't get the params id, but I get it correctly in my view and my controller.

Comment: I've done the change, but still undefined... even though I want to display param I only got : [object Object]